# How to unset EOL option in TCP packet with scapy

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I've been messing around with scapy in Python, but more specifically, I've been creating packets and trying to set the options in the TCP layer.

I know I can create a packet with

```
>>> a = IP()/TCP()
```

I also know I can set the options in the TCP layer by

```
>>> a[TCP].options=[('MSS',1200),('NOP',None)]
```

Or

```
>>> a[TCP].options=('MSS',1200),('NOP',None)
```

The problem I am having is after I sent the packet and observe it in wireshark.  Wireshark always shows that the End of List (EOL) option is set in my packets when I don't set it.  I don't think that option is always set no matter what because I've seen plenty of TCP packets without that option displayed.  Is there a way to set the TCP options in scapy WITHOUT including the EOL option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a matter of alignment I think. No need for Wireshark to check that. From scapy, you can either use `TCP(str(TCP(options=...)))` to force Scapy to build the packet and parse the resulting bytes, or use the `.show2()` packet method.

The `('MSS', 1200)` option alone needs 4 bytes, so it won't need any extra option added:

```
>>> TCP(str(TCP(options=[('MSS',1200)]))).options
WARNING: No IP underlayer to compute checksum. Leaving null.
[('MSS', 1200)]
```

The `('NOP', None)` option fits in only 1 byte, so 3 null bytes will be added. The first one will show as `('EOL', None)` and of course, as `EOL` means End Of List, the two next bytes won't be considered.

```
>>> TCP(str(TCP(options=[('NOP', None)]))).options
WARNING: No IP underlayer to compute checksum. Leaving null.
[('NOP', None), ('EOL', None)]
```

The reason why you need 4 bytes alignment is that the data offset field (`dataofs`) means "number of 4-byte words from the beginning of the `TCP` layer to the beginning of the data".